# WPF filter datagrid through textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, datagrid

I have been searching everywhere and I cannot find a way to filter my datagrid based on my textBox's value.
I have a simple `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid Name="myGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="399" 
                  Margin="272,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="735"/>
```

When my form loads. I have this function to fill datagrid :

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myGrid.ItemsSource = datatable;
}
```

I have a `TextBox` name "txtSearch" and my goal is to filter the datagrid and find all rows that contain txtSearch.Text (and hide the other rows)

Could someone provide an example ?

Comment: Is there a special field you want to filter on or all fields?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé I would like to filter every field

Comment: That doesn't help me. I need a example for my exact problem (I don't add items to the datagrid but I fill it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the [RowFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `DataView` to a filter expression. This is how you would filter a `DataTable`.

Here is a basic example that should give you the idea:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DataTable _dataTable;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dataTable = new DataTable();
        _dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
        _dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id"));
        _dataTable.Rows.Add("First", "1");
        _dataTable.Rows.Add("Second", "2");
        myGrid.ItemsSource = _dataTable.DefaultView;
    }

    private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string filter = txtSearch.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
            _dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
        else
            _dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name Like '%{0}%' OR Id Like '%{0}%'", filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply this method but when the information comes from a `List<object>` ?